# Override operator in two different ways (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators, overriding

I want to multiply a list by a certain scalar, the list includes only integers.
So we have a class and there is the function __mul__(self,scalar).
This override only supports this type of input: list * scalar.
But when I try to input scalar * list I get a TypeError.
How can I support both ways of multiplication?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you when we do not know the definition of `_mul_()` and without the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Could you show your code?